# How to use XPath to find a node using just an attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

If I have a (fragment of) xml like this:

```
<flowreferences>
<ref>123</ref>
<ref>563</ref>
<ref>902</ref>
<ref>674</ref>
<ref>295</ref>
<ref>887</ref>
<ref>371</ref>
</flowreferences>
<object1 id="123">
......
</object1>
<object1 id="563">
......
</object2>
<object2 id="887">
......
</object2>
<object3 id="674">
......
</object3>
<object4 id="295">
......
</object4>
<object5 id="907">
......
</object5>
<object6 id="371">
......
</object6>
```

Is there a Xpath query to return the object node given JUST the attribute value? In other words, if I know the id value (907), how do I find the object5 node?

Answer (score 1):

This XPath will select all `object5` elements with `id` attributes values of `"907"`:

```
//object5[@id="907"]
```

This XPath will select all elements with `id` attributes values of `"907"`:

```
//*[@id="907"]
```

Comment: And `//*[contains(local-name(), 'object') and @id='907']` should select all elements containing `object` and `@id='907'` in case that id number is used somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @JackFleeting: Thanks, note, though that testing `local-name()` alone bypasses namespaces and using `contains()` means that elements such as `not_this_object` with such an `id` value will also be selected.  But, yes, that's one way to ignore the numeric suffix tacked onto the `object` element names.